# SWT Table only first column selected

Tags: java, swt

I currently have a populated SWT table with the following styles:

```
    SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION | SWT.MULTI | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL
```

used `SWT.FULL_SELECTION` to get the whole line selected if clicked.
but using `table.getSelection()` only returns the first column.
I don't have any tableviewer or something else set.

where did I make a mistake?

edit:
example:

```
if (table.getSelectionCount() > 0) {
  for (TableItem item : table.getSelection()) {
    System.out.println(item);
  }
}
```

this returns only the first column

Comment: `getSelection()` returns all selected `TableItem`s. Why do you think you're only getting the first column?

Comment: well I'd say SWT.FULL_SELECTION still only really selects the first column. but not sure how to handle it

Comment: So you're saying the "visual selection" is only the first column, i.e. the blue colored background (or whichever color your OS uses)? BTW: Which OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using Eclipse running Windows 7. the "visual selection" is the whole line (the blue colored background). but running table.getSelection() only returns the first column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are only calling `System.out.println()` on the whole `TableItem`, Java will internally use `TableItem#toString()` to convert it to a `String`.

The resulting string however, will not contain all the data of the `TableItem`.

Instead, you'll need to iterate over the columns to get the data using `TableItem#getText(int column)`:

```
for(int i = 0; i < table.getColumnCount(); i++)
    System.out.println(item.getText(i));
```

Comment: thanks should have been able to get that on my own. shame on me

Comment: @TwelveDollar No worries, I was kind of surprised myself that the toString method works this way in the table item.